# Rearrange complicated string with sed

Tags: regex, text, awk, sed

I have some file with strings like:

```
Author    = {A. Williams and  A.~G. Clarke and  M. Pourkashanian},
```

I need to rearrange the initials after surname, separated by commas like:

```
Author    = {Williams, A. and  Clarke, A.~G. and Pourkashanian, M.},
```

All names separated by keyword `and`.

How to do this with `sed`?

My attempt

```
sed.exe -i "/^ *author *=/ s/(\{|and )([A-Za-z]{2,}) ([A-Za-z]\.[A-Za-z]\.)\}/\1\3 \2/g" file.bib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^Author/!b;h;s/.*\{(.*)\}.*/\1/;s/(\S+\.) (\S+)/\2, \1/g;G;s/(.*)\n(.*\{)[^}]*/\2\1/' file
```

Focus on only lines that begin `Author`. Copy the line to the hold space, we will need the parts we don't change to reassemble with the parts that we do. Remove the front and the back of the line i.e. the parts before the `{` and the parts after the `}`. Globally switch the initials with the surname and introduce a `,` between them. Append the original line and then replace the original names and initials with the new formatted ones.

Comment: In my file there are many strings like `some_key ={some_value},`, how can I treat only strings beginning with `author` as a key

Answer (score 1):

Strictly if your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you on same.

```
awk -F"= " -v s1=", " '{printf $1 OFS FS OFS "{";gsub(/}|{|,$/,"",$2);;num=split($2,array," and ");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){split(array[i],array2," ");printf("%s%s",array2[2] s1 array2[1],i!=num?" and ":"")}print "},"}' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F"= " -v s1=", " '{
  printf $1 OFS FS OFS "{";
  gsub(/}|{|,$/,"",$2);
  num=split($2,array," and ");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    split(array[i],array2," ");
    printf("%s%s",array2[2] s1 array2[1],i!=num?" and ":"")}
  print "},"
}' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```